# Android: C2DM Invalid Registration Error

Tags: android, curl, android-c2dm

Everything appears to work fine, until I try to push out a notification; the app gets a registration id, and the server gets an Auth code, but apparently the registration id is invalid.

When I run the PHP code after getting the registration from the app, it returns `Error=InvalidRegistration`

I am going to post all of my code for both the C2DM implementation and the server side CURL requests.

Inside OnCreate:

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "MYEMAIL");
startService(registrationIntent);
```

C2DM class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class C2DMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String receiver = context.getPackageName() + ".C2DMReceiver";
        intent.setClassName(context, receiver);
        context.startService(intent);

        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            handleRegistration(context, intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            handleMessage(context, intent);
        }
    }

    private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id"); 
        if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null) {
            // Registration failed, should try again later.
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("unregistered") != null) {
            // unregistration done, new messages from the authorized sender will be rejected
        } else if (registration != null) {
            // Send the registration ID to the 3rd party site that is sending the messages.
            // This should be done in a separate thread.
            // When done, remember that all registration is done. 
            sendReg(registration, context);
            Toast.makeText(context, registration, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    }

    public void sendReg(String key, Context context)
    {
        //Send key to server, this works fine
    }
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
// get Auth from Google ClientLogin
$new = shell_exec("curl -d accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE -d Email=MYEMAIL -d Passwd=MYPASSWORD -d service=ac2dm -d source=MYSOURCE -k https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin | grep Auth=");
$auth = substr($new, 5); // "DQAAAKY..."

$fp = fopen('/home/me/Desktop/test.txt','w');
fputs($fp, $new."\nAuth: ".$auth."\n");

// ID is from the app
$id = "APA91b...";
fputs($fp, "ID: ".$id."\n\n");

$msg = "hello";

// if I don't include ContentLength, Google tells me I need it
$len = strlen("registration_id=".$id."&data.message=".$msg."&collapse_key=something");
fputs($fp, "Len: ".$len."\n\n");

$info = shell_exec("curl --header \"Content-Length: ".$len."\" --header \"Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$auth."\" -d registration_id=".$id." -d data.message=".$msg." -d collapse_key=something -k https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");

fputs($fp, $info); // "Error=InvalidRegistration"
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the whole packet is being sent correctly? Try using fputs with both lines where you use shell_exec to make sure it's formatted correctly. I don't see anything besides that which you're doing wrong...

Comment: wow, the second shell_exec has a newline character in the middle of it, from where I grep the auth code. It's working now :)